# Why Daylight Saving is not detected by Javascript in my code?

Tags: javascript, date, dst

I have tried below code to detect if Daylight Saving is observed or not, but although it's on, it always says it's not observed.

```js
var myDate = new Date();
document.write(myDate.getTimezoneOffset());
var rightNow = new Date();
var jan1 = new Date(rightNow.getFullYear(), 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var temp = jan1.toUTCString();
var jan2 = new Date(temp.substring(0, temp.lastIndexOf(" ")-1));
var std_time_offset = (jan1 - jan2) / (1000 * 60 * 60);
var june1 = new Date(rightNow.getFullYear(), 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
temp = june1.toUTCString();
var june2 = new Date(temp.substring(0, temp.lastIndexOf(" ")-1));
var daylight_time_offset = (june1 - june2) / (1000 * 60 * 60);
var dst;
if (std_time_offset == daylight_time_offset) {
    dst = "0"; // daylight savings time is NOT observed
} else {
    dst = "1"; // daylight savings time is observed
}
```

It's currently returning me "not oberserved", no matter which way I am using.  (Can't add all methods here as it will be too long question)

Hence, I just want to confirm:

1. Does that require any settings in my machine?
2. Is there any specific country you have to be in to get this observed?

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 2):

That code seems really complicated for what it needs to do. Here's a simple function that makes the same assumption you do (that DST is not in effect on Jan 1st of the year) and detects whether DST is in effect for the given `Date` instance:

```js
function isDST(dt) {
  // Northern or southern hemisphere?
  // NOTE: Assumes that Jan 1st (southern hemisphere) or July 1st (northern hemisphere) will be DST
  // This may be a "good enough" assumption, but if not, you'll need to download timezone information
  const jan1 = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
  const jul1 = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
  const ref = jan1.getTimezoneOffset() < jul1.getTimezoneOffset() ? jul1 : jan1;
  return dt.getTimezoneOffset() !== ref.getTimezoneOffset();
}
console.log(isDST(new Date(2018, 6, 1))); // true (if July 1st is DST in your timezone)
console.log(isDST(new Date(2018, 1, 1))); // false (if Feb 1st is not DST in your timezone)
```

It takes advantage of the fact that `getTimezoneOffset` includes the DST offset if DST is in effect.

Of course, if a location should change the timezone it's in permanently between the two dates, it would give a false positive, but that's a relatively rare occurrence.

Comment: Thanks !! Have tried this code also before !! If I am adding isDST(new Date(2018, 04, 02)), which supposed to be DST true as per today !, but its still showing me False.  is there any idea? Any setting I need to make for country wise or something like that ?

Comment: @CodeWithCoffee: *"`isDST(new Date(2018, 04, 02))`, which supposed to be DST true as per today"* That's **May** 2nd, not April 2nd. (But I'd expect the answer to be the same in most locales.) Also, be sure not to iniclude leading zeros on numeric literals (not least because in strict mode, it's an error). `isDST(new Date(2018, 3, 2))` (e.g., today) returns `true` for me here in the UK (where we are indeed on "British Summer Time").

Comment: In my chrome browser, its still showing me False for isDST(new Date(2018, 3, 2)) !! I am in India

Comment: @CodeWithCoffee: Where in India are you? According to [this well-referenced site](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/india/mumbai), there is no DST in, say, Mumbai, at all in 2018. (In fact, it seems to say that no part of India officially uses DST: https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/india )

Comment: Thanks !! However, what if my this code execute from client end in UK / Somewhere where DST is there ? Its showing Daylight enabled time there when they execute my above code ?

Comment: @CodeWithCoffee: Yes, this tests for DST *on the client*. JavaScript on the client can't test for DST elsewhere (other than querying the information from some server).

Answer (score 1):

The OP has been modified since my original answer so that it no longer applies. T.J. has alternative code, but so as not to waste an answer, here's a similar function that:

1. Gets the timezone offset for 1 Jan and 1 Jul for the related year
2. Assumes DST is in force and returns true if either:

   - the place observes DST as for the southern hemisphere DST (i.e. Jan offset is less than Jul offset, noting that javascript offsets are the opposite sense of ISO and all other commonly used systems) and the offset is the same as for January
   - the place observes DST as for the northern hemisphere DST (same caveat as above) and the offset is the same as for July
3. For any other case (jan offset equals jul offset so no DST at all, or date offset is as for non–DST offset) the date must not be in DST

```js
function inDST(inDate) {
  var inOffset  = inDate.getTimezoneOffset();
  var janOffset = new Date(inDate.getFullYear(), 0, 1).getTimezoneOffset();
  var julOffset = new Date(inDate.getFullYear(), 6, 1).getTimezoneOffset();
  return (janOffset < julOffset && janOffset == inOffset) ||
         (janOffset > julOffset && julOffset == inOffset);
}

// Just a helper for testing
function fDate(d) {
  var z = n => (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
  return `${z(d.getDate())}-${d.toLocaleString(undefined, {month:'short'})}-${d.getFullYear()}`;
}

// Tests
[new Date(2018, 1, 2),  //  2 Feb 2018
 new Date(2018, 5, 30)] // 30 Jun 2018
 .forEach(d =>
  console.log(`${fDate(d)}: ${inDST(d)}`)
);
```

Comment: Need to convert it in Date ?

Comment: @CodeWithCoffee—the OP has been changed since I wrote that answer, so it no longer applies.